# XD Soft - DateTimePicker - Same Day - Time Slot Color on focus/Clicked is not changing

Tags: background-color, datetimepicker, bootstrap-datetimepicker, onfocus, jquerydatetimepicker

Issue is on same day background Color for Time slot will not change when clicked or selected.
It is selected and emails are sent also but only issue is it will not change color when selected.

For next day it works fine, roll over and clicked color changes
Issue comes when some time-slots are disabled
Timings are 10-7
For example on same day its 4:00 Now so it disables previous time-slot and If i want to select later time slots then it will not change the color.
Any suggestions?

Tried changing code but none worked Should I paste code here?